# How to submit multiple street2coordinates requests? (R)

Tags: r, gis

I know how to use street2coordinates to get the lat and lon for one address, but what if I have a vector of 100 and I want to just add new fields to the data frame with the lat and long values? This seems like it should be simple but I can't figure it out.

The addresses are contained in dataset$fulladdress.

(I am eventually trying to turn a bunch of addresses by census tract and map them. If there's a better way to do that, let me know)

Thanks!

Comment: The above link answers a slightly different question, but in the process deals with yours. The street2coordinate function uses the GET interface to DSTK which only allows one address. You could vectorise it using Vectorize but it would be quicker to use httr and the POST interface as done in the linked answer.

Comment: OK thanks - I saw that before but didn't quite get it. I'll try as you've written. Let me know if I should delete this as a duplicate. Thanks